# Replacing a flag in a string with an image, infinite times

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've got a remotely loaded string and inside the string is a large portion of text. In parts of the text there is a flag which is basically the word 'image' surrounded by excelemation marks (like so: !image!) - think of it as a placeholder for the image.

What I'm trying to do is have javascript replace !image! with an actual piece of html:

```
<img src="./images/the_image.png" class="image">
```

I know its possible to simply do this:

```
var theString = 'some string goes here !image!';
theString.replace('!image!', '<img src="./images/the_image.png" class="image">');
```

However this does not allow you to do multiple replaces.

Is there a way of replacing all here? I'm assuming regex may be an option but unfortunately cant figure out where to even start with it due to it having symbols (the exclamation marks) in the condition.

I have looked at the related posts on SO and none of them work (again I assume due to the symbols).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use regex delimiters
2. Don't use quote for regex
3. Use `g` flag for global replacement

So fixed statement is:

```
theString.replace(/!image!/g, '<img src="./images/the_image.png" class="image">');
```